# External repository and repository implementation

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

The repository that is being used in the Spring Boot application (this is located in the main module):

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String>, AzureRepository<Person, String> {

}
```

The repository and implementation of the repository (these are located in a different maven module):

```
public interface AzureRepository<T, ID> {

    boolean customUpdate(T entity);

}

public class AzureRepositoryImpl<T, ID> implements AzureRepository<T, ID> {
  ...
}
```

This configuration produces the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property customUpdate found for type Person!
```

The custom repository and its implementation works fine when everything is in the same maven module. But when the custom repository and its implementation are placed in the utility maven module then the error from above gets thrown.

Comment: Maybe because spring is not scanning those beans because they are in different package. Check value of scanBasePackages for ```@SpringBootApplication``` .

Comment: @Harshit Its being picked up by spring as a bean but it doesnt link the impl bean as a repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `@EnableJpaRepositories` I should've used `@EnableMongoRepositories` to specify the base package of the external repositories.